# Community Ads - 2017 Edition

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I think it's time it's we refresh our [community ad post](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/create-an-ad-for-this-site) from last year so we can allow new ideas to be considered by the community. As such, here's the official community ad message for 2017 that's been [circulating](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9028/community-promotion-ads-2017):

> ### What are Community Promotion Ads?
>
> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
>   show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
>   question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
>   provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
>   shown.
>
> ### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?
>
> This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to
>   visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following
>   things:
>
> cool server utilities the site's twitter account script packs or power
>   tools cool events or conferences anything else your community would
>   genuinely be interested in The goal is for future visitors to find out
>   about the stuff your community deems important. This also serves as a
>   way to promote information and resources that are relevant to your own
>   community's interests, both for those already in the community and
>   those yet to join.
>
> ### Why do we reset the ads every year?
>
> Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other
>   things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads
>   every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served
>   their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This
>   helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject
>   matter of the community, but to the current status of the community.
>   We reset the ads once a year, every December.
>
> The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an
>   ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very
>   valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good
>   idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the
>   process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale
>   after a year of exposure.
>
> ### How does it work?
>
> The answers you post to this question must conform to the following
>   rules, or they will be ignored.
>
> All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
> ```
> [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>    [1]: http://image-url
>    [2]: http://clickthrough-url
> ```
>
> Please do not add anything else to the body of the post. If you want
>   to discuss something, do it in the comments. The question must always
>   be tagged with the magic community-ads tag. In addition to enabling
>   the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the
>   answer form with the above required form. Image requirements
>
> The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if
>   high DPI. Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
>   Must be GIF or PNG No animated GIFs Absolute limit on file size of 150
>   KB If the background of the image is white or partially white, there
>   must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it. Score Threshold
>
> There is a minimum score threshold an answer must meet (currently 6)
>   before it will be shown on the main site.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Language Learning Stack Exchange Advertisement]

[v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAupZ.png)

[v1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcaIc.png)

Comment: Could you replace the gray with a darker colour that provides more contrast with the background? See [this comment from last year](http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/231/create-an-ad-for-this-site#comment695_308).

Comment: I really like this one. It's clean, elegant, and gets the point across +1

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Working on more accessible colors right now

Comment: Okay, that's the last edit I'll be able to make today.

Comment: Contrast is better now; thanks.

Comment: I think you should consider submitting this to the Japanese Language, English Language Learners, and English Language and Usage meta community ad posts for 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I'm resubmitting [one of my entries from last year](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/328/800):

[image: ad for Language Learning Stack Exchange with 9 different languages]

Русский is Russian, አማርኛ is Amharic, తెలుగు is Telugu, हिन्दी is Hindi. 希腊语 is Chinese for "Greek".

I created the image in Inkscape and exported it to PNG. The image is available under a Creative Commons licence; you can also use it on other websites and on blogs.

Comment: Would anyone care to explain the rationale behind the downvotes?

Comment: At the very least, have the text in the red box be English. Not to be a harsh critic but this ad could look a but more professional.

Comment: I think you should consider submitting this to the Japanese Language, English Language Learners, and English Language and Usage meta community ad posts for 2017.